# why mongodb find limit doesn't limit any document in the result set

Tags: mongodb

I use below command to find documents in mongodb shell.

```
> db.companies.find().limit(1).count()
18801
```

you can see the output is 18801 which means the `limit(1)` function doesn't have any impact on the command. Did I miss anything wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`count`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/cursor.count/#cursor.count) accepts an optional `applySkipLimit` parameter for this purpose. So use `count(true)` if you want its result to consider the effects of `skip` and `limit`:

```
> db.companies.find().limit(1).count(true)
1
```